# Selecting alternate divs

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have code sort of like this:

```
<div class="right_col">

   <div class="right_box">
      <div class="other_div">text</div>
      text etc
   </div>

   <div class="right_box">
      <div class="other_div">text</div>
      text etc
   </div>


   <div class="right_box">
      <div class="other_div">text</div>
      <div class="anotherother_div">text</div>
      text etc
   </div>

   <div class="right_box">
      text etc
   </div>

</div>
```

So a main div with other divs inside which may or may not contain additional divs.
What I want to do is style them so "right_box" has alternate background colours.
The problem is that I am selecting the interior divs/taking them into account when doing odd/even etc.

This is the CSS I've tried:

```
.right_col .right_col:nth-child(even) {background:red}
.right_col .right_col:nth-child(0n+1) {background:red}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Use `nth-of-type()` instead of `nth-child`.

Comment: Thanks! Post this as the answer and I'll mark it for you. Does the type refer to .right_col then?

Comment: Done. Posted an article that explains the difference as well. And yes, like `:nth-child()`, `:nth-of-type()` refers to (the second) `.right_col`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `nth-of-type()` rather then `nth-child()`.

**[Here's an awesome article on CSS-Tricks by Chris Coyer which explains the difference between the two.](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)**